# Dynamic drop-down lists in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

i want to know how to make dynamic drop down list in Google Sheets, e.g I have a list of continents in "Continent" column (data validation applied) and want to validate the next column with only countries that fall on previous selected continent.  [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycKBsHBRjVExPztN_VFj9q1P2i7KVmWmGnVx_uhivPc/edit?usp=sharing)

It would be helpful to solve this without script.
If it required script please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this without a script involves a helper list. Here are the steps:

- Create Named Ranges for Each of Your Lists
- Link a Column to the first dropdown using `ARRAYFORMULA` and `INDIRECT`
- Set data validation of the second dropdown to that entire column being populated by `ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT())`

[image]

You can see the working example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Snn2ZpDTpb1I96ihsRHcUqvgsijiHPQNqqRD9bc-1_A/edit?usp=sharing